# sorting gives wrong output for the element at last position

Tags: c++, c, sorting, quicksort, bubble-sort

I am trying to clear some basic concepts os programming. I preferred doing sorting for this.
Below is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include <string.h>


main()
{ 
    int array[9]={5,2,7,4,7,6,9,8,1,3};
    int min,i,j,temp;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=10;j++)
        {
            if(array[i]<array[j])
            {
                temp=array[j];
                array[j]=array[i];
                array[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ", array[i] );
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And the output is :

```
1  2  4  5  6  7  7  8  9  9
```

which is unexpected. It must be

```
1  2  3   4  5  6  7  7  8  9
```

Could some one help me to know why this strange behavior at the end of the array. Why it **repeats "9"** and Where has **"3" lost** ? 
Also i appreciate if some one tell me name of best sorting (Mostly i have heard of Bubble and quick sort, but why and what is the difference that i don't know). **Please dont tell me about in built functions (like qsort() and etc.) because the objective is to clear concepts**
You can any language to explain c/c++/ or even algorithm. Thanks

Comment: You have 10 elements, not 11. Change your for loop.

Comment: You have an array of nine elements, and initialize it with ten. And loop over ten as elements as well, except in one case where you loop over eleven elements.

Comment: I suggest you create a new variable to contain the number of elements in the array: `const size_t element_count = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);` Then use that in your loops.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry couldnt understand your last comment ? Any algo or piece of code to explain please ? I have done the suggested changes and it works fine now.Also i appreciate if you tell me name of best sorting (Mostly i have heard of Bubble and quick sort, but why and what is the difference that i don't know).

Comment: I would argue that in C++ the best sorting is [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). As for the use of that variable, you do like `for (size_t i = 0; i < element_count; ++i) ...`, then you won't loop outside the bounds of the array. Note: Only works with "real" arrays, not arrays that has decayed to pointers. Also, instead of using arrays, consider [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify an array of 9 elements, and yet you have 10 elements in the initialiser and in your outer loop:

```
int array[9]={5,2,7,4,7,6,9,8,1,3};
       // ^- this is not the last index, but the number of elements!

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
```

And here you iterate up to index 10, which is the 11th element (index 0 is the first):

```
for(j=0;j<=10;j++)
        //^- when j is 10 this is still true, but there is no array[10]
```

To fix, change to the following:

```
int array[] = {5,2,7,4,7,6,9,8,1,3};
      //  ^- leave empty and let the compiler count the elements
const int array_len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
      //  length:     ^- whole array / ^- one element

for (i = 0; i < array_len; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < array_len; ++j) {
```

Comment: please see the edited code, The output is still same even after making following changes

Comment: Yaah that worked. But i have some doubt (1) Does the index of array starts from "0" or "1" , I thought "0" thats why i kept it"9" for 10 elements. (2) Which sort is this ? and which sort is better ?

Comment: @user234839 1) Array index starts from 0, but in the declaration of the array `int array[9]` the `9` is not an index, but the number of elements, i.e., `int array[10]` declares an array with 10 elements, indexed 0..9 inclusive.

Comment: Yaah that worked. But i have some doubt (1) Does the index of array starts from "0" or "1" , I thought "0" thats why i kept it"9" for 10 elements. (2) Which sort is this ? and which sort is better ? –

Comment: @user234839 2) If you want a better sort that's easy to implement, try insertion sort or selection sort (see, e.g., wikipedia). Quicksort is better still but somewhat harder to implement in C. For real use (as opposed to programming practice) just use the standard library `qsort`.

Comment: Is there any name specified for the sort i am using ?(Isn't it a bubble sort?).

Comment: @user234839 I don't think it's strictly bubble sort, but rather like an inefficient variant of selection sort.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48688/discussion-between-user234839-and-arkku)

Answer (score 4):

`for(j=0;j<=10;j++)` will give you *undefined behaviour* since you're accessing outside the array bounds with your subsequent `array[j]`.

`int array[9]={5,2,7,4,7,6,9,8,1,3};` is also unbalanced, you need `int array[10]` since you have 10 elements in your initialiser list. Better still, let the compiler do the work for you and write `int array[]`. This is why `3` is currently omitted from your output (notwithstanding the undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 2):

`array[9]`; `i < 10`; `j <= 10`. array index out of bounds. undefined behaviour.

`i` and `j` should be checked like `i < 9` and `j < 9`

```
int array[9]={5,2,7,4,7,6,9,8,1,3};
```

And you have **10** elements in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, any code should be added using the code button so that it is formatted properly and easy to read.

Secondly, you're array is too small. It's size is 9 but you have 10 items.